# How to add html tags to string, avoiding nested tags

Tags: python, html, regex

I have a string that contain text and html tags in it (only such tags: `<a href=""></a>`).

How do I decorate the text outside of the "a" tag with "i" tag, avoiding nested tags (like: `<i><a href=""></a></i>`).

**What I want to achieve:**

```
<i>some text</i><a href="link">link text</a><i>another text in the message</i>
```

The text outside the "a" tags is decorated with "i" tags without "i" tags around "a".

I was thinking about:

1. Split string by tags using regular expression
2. For each item in the result list add `<i>` tags
3. "$".join(list from step#2)
4. Replace "$" with "a" tags that were removed when splitting.

Could someone advise me anything better, because I don't think it is a good way to do it.

**UPDATE:**
Added original string example:

```
some text<a href="link">link text</a>another text in the message
```

The solution from **Michael Butscher** worked for me as expected.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `'<i>some text</i>' + original_string + '<i>more text</i>'` ?

Comment: If you just want to enclose the whole string in `<i>...</i>` without the links then a simple `s = "<i>" + s.replace('<a href=', '</i><a href=').replace('</a>', '</a><i>') + '</i>'` should do.

Comment: @"Michael Butscher" I think he mentioned that he wanted to avoid doubling up though because some tags already have `<i>` tags although the description of the problem is really unclear

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you, sir! This is extremly simple and did the trick for me.

Comment: @FailSafe sorry for that, I "refactored" the question multiple times before posting it and accidentally removed the original string which I tried to modify. P.S. the original string only contained <a> tags, no <i> tags in the original string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454?r=SearchResults&s=2|492.4331#1732454

Comment: @"Vasya Run" Ok. No problem.

Comment: @Toto You know, I've seen that, and as someone who has parsed xml/html multiple times with regex, I'd counter that it is "situational." There are cases where it is a bad idea, but there are many where it is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

**Sooo, I'd say you need to change the description of this problem to be a bit more clear, but trying to figure this out is awesome. I might even fork this to see if it can be done in one step. This takes into account documents where you already have some `<i>` tags.**

Hopefully, this works

```
>>> string = ''' <a href=""></a>   <i><a href=""></a></i> '''


>>> def add_i_tags(string):
        import re
        new_string = re.sub(r'(?<!<i>)(<a)', r'<i>\1', string)
        new_string = re.sub(r'(/a>)(?!</i>)', r'\1</i>', new_string)
        return new_string



>>> added_to_string = add_i_tags(string)





#Output

>>> print(added_to_string)

<i><a href=""></a></i>   <i><a href=""></a></i>
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion, the question was missing details indeed.